# Unable to achieve wanted entry textBox alignment

Tags: python, tkinter

HI i am trying to place the alignment of my Entry(Text Box) according to the image below. I tried everything, TOP BOTTOM LEFT RIGHT.

## This is the alignment i want. Obtained from paint program*

[image]

## Problem

[image]

## Coding of tkinter

```
master = Tk.Tk() # Open up GUI connection
master.title('Program Application')
print "VSM activated input range first (X2 must be larger than X1)"
#Declare button and respective method
button = Tk.Button(text='VSM', command=VSM, fg="red")
button.config( height = 10, width = 80 )
button.pack() #pack is needed to display the button
bluebutton = Tk.Button(text="AGM Folder",command= lambda: Folder(0), fg="blue").pack(side = LEFT)
bluebutton = Tk.Button(text="VSM Folder",command= lambda: Folder(1), fg="blue").pack(side = RIGHT)
Label(text='Correct Range for Gradient\nX2                                                                                                               X1').pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
entryX2 = Entry(master, width=10)
entryX2.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
entryX1 = Entry(master,width=10)
entryX1.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=10,pady=10)
buttonGradient = Tk.Button(text='Input Range OP',command= lambda: Folder(2), fg="red").pack()
entryX2IP = Entry(master, width=10)
entryX2IP.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
entryX1IP = Entry(master,width=10)
entryX1IP.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=10,pady=10)
btnGradientIP = Tk.Button(text='Input Range IP',command= lambda: Folder(2), fg="red").pack(side = TOP)
master.mainloop() # Continue loop till user close tab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Frame`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm):

```
master = Tk.Tk() # Open up GUI connection
master.title('Program Application')
print "VSM activated input range first (X2 must be larger than X1)"
#Declare button and respective method
button = Tk.Button(text='VSM', command=VSM, fg="red")
button.config( height = 10, width = 80 )
button.pack() #pack is needed to display the button
bluebutton = Tk.Button(text="AGM Folder",command= lambda: Folder(0), fg="blue").pack(side = LEFT)
bluebutton = Tk.Button(text="VSM Folder",command= lambda: Folder(1), fg="blue").pack(side = RIGHT)
Label(text='Correct Range for Gradient\nX2                                                                                                               X1').pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)

################### Use 3 frames to contains entries, buttons.
frameX2 = Frame(master)
frameX2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, anchor=E)
entryX2 = Entry(frameX2, width=10)
entryX2.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
entryX2IP = Entry(frameX2, width=10)
entryX2IP.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
frameButton = Frame(master)
frameButton.pack(side=LEFT)
Tk.Button(frameButton, text='Input Range OP',command= lambda: Folder(2), fg="red").pack(padx=10, pady=10)
Tk.Button(frameButton, text='Input Range IP',command= lambda: Folder(2), fg="red").pack(padx=10, pady=10)
frameX1 = Frame(master)
frameX1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, anchor=W)
entryX1 = Entry(frameX1,width=10)
entryX1.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
entryX1IP = Entry(frameX1,width=10)
entryX1IP.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
#####################

master.mainloop() # Continue loop till user close tab
```

[image: result screenshot]